# JFrame is not refreshed after minimize on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, swing, jframe

I made a java swing application, and it needs to run on Windows as well as Mac OS X.

When the user clicks on the minimize button, the application is minimized, and an icon is created in system tray with the following code:

```
MainScreen.getInstance().setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);

trayIcon = new TrayIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
       "/dragonstore/resources/icon.png")).getImage());

trayIcon.setToolTip("DragonStore");
trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
trayIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
     @Override
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
           {
           MainScreen.getInstance().setVisible(true);

           MainScreen.getInstance().setExtendedState(NORMAL);
           SystemTray.getSystemTray().remove(trayIcon);
           trayIcon=null;
           MainScreen.getInstance().toFront();
           MainScreen.getInstance().getMainPanel().revalidate();
           MainScreen.getInstance().getMainPanel().repaint();
           MainScreen.getInstance().pack();
           MainScreen.getInstance().validate();
           MainScreen.getInstance().repaint();
           System.out.println("Restore");
       }
});
SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(trayIcon);
trayIcon.displayMessage("DragonStore",
        "Click here to maximized window again",TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
setVisible(false);
```

So above code executes fine, and when the user clicks on the system tray icon, the application is restored by the code in `trayIcon` Mouse Clicked function.

Every thing goes fine on Windows with no problems anywhere.

**But on Mac OS X when I restore the application, it appears with all components in animated style which is default on Mac, but once it fully restores on screen the window displays a blank window, as if the frame had no components.**

I looked into the problem and found a redraw of frames bug in Mac OS X Lion, but I do not expect it is the issue here.

What should I do to solve this?

My objective is to make minimized applications be invisible from the task bar and the icon shows up in a system tray notification, so the user can restore the application by clicking on system tray icon.

**It must be executed both on Windows and Mac.**

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I'd guess it relates to the apparently random flailing of calls to .validate, .pack, .revalidate, etc.  I'm not sure you should need much more than setVisible(true) or possibly the setExtendedState(NORMAL) that you have in your code.

Comment: Actually the task bar operation is not support on MAC, so there is no need to setVisible(false) when on MAC. so i remove all code for the MAC version which is inside in windowStateListener function. Now every thing works fine both on MAC and Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
What should I do to solve this?
```

use

1. `JFrame#setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);` instead of `MainScreen.getInstance().setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);`
2. `MainScreen.getInstance().setVisible(true);` should be last line (`and only one code line`) in `public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)`, every code lines are useless, because `JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE` only to hide `JFrame`,
3. `Every thing goes fine on Windows with no problems anywhere.` I doubt ..., but for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)